# Running Firebase TestLab XCTest on iOS 15 devices

Tags: ios, firebase, xctest, firebase-test-lab

I wonder if it's possible to run XCTest via Firebase TestLab on iOS15+ devices/simulators.
 I will describe my problem with `gcloud command line` first:
When running this command in terminal:
`gcloud firebase test ios models list`
It returns me this devices and os versions list:
[image]

And looks like the latest available OS version to run is `14.7` which is available on `iPhone8` only.
However, this command: 
`gcloud firebase test ios versions list`
returns me a lot more available versions, including `15.1` as the latest iOS version:
[image]
Also, here is the image from Firebase TestLab console, which lists the only available devices just like the first command I mentioned:
[image]

... So, is there any way to run my tests on iOS 15 via Firebase TestLab?

Answer (score 0):

iOS 15+ is not yet supported on Firebase Test Lab. It's in the works, but there's currently no ETA.

Comment: Note: you see the 15.1 version in the catalog before the devices appear in the catalog because it is necessary for the version to be present first in order to add the necessary device support.

Comment: @P.Davis is there an approximate date of when they will support iOS 15+ versions? Also, Firebase TestLab supports only physical iOS devices, not simulators like Android, right?

Comment: As Faith noted, an exact ETA is not known yet. And Test Lab does not offer iOS simulators at the present time.